# Castle.Windsor code review

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am using Castle.Windsor in one factory class to create instance of required class.
You can find example below.

```
public class MyFactory : IDisposable
{
    protected readonly IKernel Kernel;

    protected MyFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(
            kernel.NotNull(),
            "'kernel' parameter must be initialized.");

        Kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IMyType Create(long param1, long param2)
    {
        return Kernel.Resolve<IMyType>(
            new { numberOfRows, numberOfCells });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DisposeManagedResources();
    }

    protected virtual void DisposeManagedResources()
    {
        Kernel.Dispose();
    }
}
```

1. I am not sure that I need IDisposable here... should I dispose Kernel right after disposing of MyFactory instance?
2. I am not sure that IKernel (in constructor) is the best way in order to resolve IMyType in Create method. I guess, somebody can suggest a more elegant version :)

Any other ideas?

Thank you advance.

Comment: Hmm.. I think ServiceLocator can help me...

Comment: Why you do this? MyFactory is used in where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, a class should only dispose resources that it owns. Since this resource is supplied from the outside, that class is not responsible for disposing it, unless the ownership for that resource is 'explicitly' passed with it. This explicitness of passing the ownership is usually done through documentation or by using common design patterns. It is quite natural for instance, that a factory method (named `CreateXXX`), passes the ownership the caller with the returned instance. DI containers on the other hand contain `Get`, `GetInstance`, or `Resolve` methods, and they don’t pass the ownership to the caller.

But besides this, in your case you are dealing with a DI container. A DI container instance should normally live for the total duration of the application. Although containers usually need disposing, calling dispose within this class will clearly be the wrong place to do so. It is not the responsibility of this factory class to do so. Since the container should live for the duration of the application, the correct place to do so is during application teardown. In a ASP.NET application for instance, this will typically be the `Application_End` event in the global.asax.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I've decided to use CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter class. 'MyFactory' classes are not required yet - ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMyType>() should create a new instance of required class. Just I cannot find how to use constructor with parameters... probably, it will be lazy initialization of parameters...

Comment: Don't use the Common Service Locator. Your application should not call into the container directly or through the Common Service Locator interface. [This article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) clearly explains why.

Comment: hmm... "a horrible developer experience"... but my factories would not have direct dependencies on container... ok, no problem, is it nice practice when my factory classes contain IKernel property to create new instance?

Comment: @MaximPolishchuk: The trick is make *application code* independent of the used container by using dependency injection (especially constructor injection). *Infrastructure code* (the [mechanics](http://bit.ly/oQysCV)) that is part of your [Composition Root](http://bit.ly/pHCoS7) (the start-up path of your app where you wire your dependencies) can take a dependency on the container without any risk. In other words, place the factory abstraction in the application, but the factory implementations in the application start-up code.